# Vim complains about a temporary file when opening syntax highlighted files on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim

When I try to open a file (e.g. test/test_sequence.rb) using Vim or MacVim I get the following error:

```
"test/test_sequence.rb" 109L, 3697C
Vim(let):E484: Can't open file /var/folders/zO/zOCN9kiiGD4keWX3TWYEh++++TI/-Tmp-/vzTkbXD/0
```

This seems only restricted to files which have some kind of syntax highlighting. I can still edit the file but I have to use :w! to write the changes the first time. I'm using vim on Mac OS X. I tried a lot of googling for this error with no luck and this has become really frustrating. Could anyone offer a fix for this?

**EDIT:** I don't get this error when editing syntax highlighted LaTeX files but do with syntax highlighted Ruby files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the shell.
Vim was trying to use /bin/screen as the shell

```
set shell /bin/sh
```

In my vimrc fixed the problem.

Comment: Just hit this myself when I changed my login shell to fishshell.  Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Same here, after setting default shell to fish it happened to me :)

Comment: Well, it had to add: `set shell=/bin/bash`.

Comment: for me the syntax had to be `set shell=/bin/sh`

Comment: But the whole thing seems filetype=ruby-specific to me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you `su` to a different user, processes trying to use temporary files may produce an error like `/var/folders/zO/zOCN9kiiGD4keWX3TWYEh++++TI/-Tmp-/vzTkbXD/0: permission denied`; the fix for this is to `unset TMPDIR` (which, I think, causes `/tmp` to be used instead), because the TMPDIR specified is specific to the old user and not writable by the current user.

You haven't said whether you're using `su` or any other user-switching, and the error message doesn't mention permission denied, but ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried changing the location of $TMPDIR to /tmp. I instead get an error pointing to /tmp/vzTkbXD/0 now though.

Comment: Try `unset TMPDIR` instead. And what is the error? If the message really doesn't show it, run `sudo fs_usage MacVim` (note that the named process *must be already running*) and note what the errno on its open() call is.

Comment: Thank you for your continued suggestions to try to resolve this for me, it's really appreciated. I've tried unsetting $TMPDIR but this doesn't resolve the error either.Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the fs_usage command and I couldn't produce an error number for the open process in the fs_usage output. I've pasted the complete output of fs_usage here if this is of any use - http://cl.ly/5c01de97b2276a73b569

Answer (score 0):

Vim is trying to open a swap file, have you tried repairing permissions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've just run disk utility's repair permissions twice but I'm still seeing the same problem.